# intel hd 4000, windows 7, triple monitors (DVI, VGA, HDMI)

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have a Core i7 3770k on Asus P8Z77-V LK and three monitors (actually one of them is TV). Two monitors were connected via DVI and VGA, I tried to connect third monitor (TV) via HDMI but it didn't work.
It worked **as expected** when I was using **any 2 of them**, but I still need 3 simultaneously.

I don't think that this is a hardware problem because everything **works on Linux** (3 monitors simultaneously).
I have updated all drivers, windows, BIOS but the problem isn't solved yet.

Pls help).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gfx card will only support 3 displays in Windows 7 if -

- If two of the displays are DisplayPort* monitors
- If one of the displays is an Intel® Wireless Display (Intel® WiDi)
- If the built-in display is an Embedded DisplayPort1 (eDP) not a LVDS

[source](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033714.htm)

As for Linux vs Windows, check out [this](https://communities.intel.com/thread/42632) discussion. Notable is active vs passive adapters..

Answer (score 2):

The [motherboard manual](http://www.asus.com/support/Manual/1/39/P8Z77V_LK/) has this:

[image: This motherboard comes with multiple VGA output that features desktop extension on two monitors. You can connect two monitors to any two of the onboard VGA, DisplayPort,DVI-D, and HDMI ports]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But it works in Linux. Why doesn't it work in Windows?

Comment: Looks like your in the gap between what is possible with the hardware and what is supported by the Intel drivers in Windows or by ASUS. The Z77 Express Chipset does have 3 independent display support listed as a feature.